# How to mimic Olympus' dramatic tone filter?

Tags: reverse-engineering, olympus, contrast, rawtherapee

I just did a few tries with some of Olympus' art filters and liked that "dramatic tone" filter. But even then, the images are far from perfect and I would like to recreate them in my raw converter (I am using Raw Therapee - but this topic shouldn't be limited to a specific tool). Does anyone know how I can achieve this?

Apparently this filter has a low global contrast but a very high local contrast. I tried reducing the overall contrast and rising microcontrast, but the result is far from what I expected. Next try would be to play around with the graduation curve (high contrast in low and high tones and low mid tones?). Any ideas or hints?

Edit: Some examples. You can find the high res images and some others [on my cloud](https://my.hidrive.com/share/2l4zmk8cg7#$/)

[image: Standard colors]
[image: Dramatic Tone]

[image: Standard colors]
[image: Dramatic Tone]

Comment: To me this looks like the images went through a HDR -> LDR conversion process.

Comment: They have a HDRish look, but are made out of one single shot. As I said, global contrast is low (or compressed). It must be possible somehow to achieve that in any RAW converter.

Comment: How did you work with global/microcontrast? Do you use Lightroom? I think "Clarity" slider has very similar effect.

Comment: @craesh: in a lot of HDR -> LDR tools you can load a single non-hdr image and process it the same way.

Answer (score 1):

Nik filters can produce a similar look. You have much better control there than with the Olympus Dramatic Tone filter.

Here is the result of an image taken at the same location at the same time :-)

[image]